# Equal area world QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

when I use ArcGIS I normally use CRS: Cylindrical Equal Area (World) WKID: 54034

In QGIS I cannot find the same projection. When I re-project my file in ArcGIS and open it in QGIS it says I am using a custom CRS:

- Generated CRS (+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs)

Is it true that QGIS doesn't have this CRS? I will use my custom CRS for now but for future projects my main question is: What is a suitable equal area projection with global coverage in QGIS? I was thinking about Lambert but can't find the right flavor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code numers `540xy`
 are not official EPSG codes, but rather invented by ESRI to fit the wish for worldwide projections.

QGIS has some of them (naming them wrongly **EPSG**:540xy). But some are missing, because noone has implemented them. That's the reason why QGIS has to create a custom CRS for it. You can safely use that, or type in `540` in the Filter search box and look what similar worldwide projections are included.

As far as I can see, Lambert projections laea and lcc are only used for parts of the world, not worldwide.

Answer (score 1):

I use only QGIS and R. I had a shape file with unknown CRS and I could not figure out which one was.

I have solved by importing the shapefile in R with the `sf` package and `myshp=st_read('myshapefile.shp')`. R recognized the projection instead (epsg:54034). Then I used st_transform to convert the coordinates as WGS84 `myshp=st_transform(myshp, "+init=epsg:4326")` and then saved again `st_write(myshp,'mynewshapefile.shp')` and opened back with QGIS.
.

Answer (score 0):

EPSG:3410 is implemented in the QGIS.
It is not the same as ArcGIS WKID:54034, however it is world equal area SRS.
More information about the SRS origin https://nsidc.org/data/atlas/epsg_3410.html

Comment: EPSG:3410 has the parameters `+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +no_defs`. As you can see, it uses a sphere, and latitude of true scale at 30°N. Surely this has an influence on the area calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question about WKID:54034 support in QGIS

Comment: nmtoken, there is also question "What is a suitable equal area projection with global coverage in QGIS?". EPSG:3410 is the answer to that question. I found only this world equal-area SRS, supported by default. Do you know about some other? Let me know, That  will be very useful also for me.